# Changing Due Date of Activity will make the Activity from Archived state to unArchived state?

Tags: event

If i change the *Due Date* of Activity which is one year older and in *Archived state* to a date less than 365 days, will it make the Activity from *Archived state* to *unArchived state*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer would be "it depends". If you have workflow rules that set an "Archive Flag" on the object record, you'd need to know what those workflow rules are. If it archives them at 365 days, the answer would be "perhaps". Unless the workflow rules run again to reset the Archive Flag when you change the Due Date for the Activity, then the answer would be no. If they do, the answer would be yes.

I suggest you open the Developer Console in your sandbox and try doing what you're talking about, then examine the log to see exactly what occurred when/if the workflow rules fired. You can also look at the workflow rules to see what they are for Activities. That should give you a better clue as to what kind of behavior to expect.

Without knowing what the archive rules are for the object, no one is going to be able to tell you what's going to happen. Normally, a workflow rules will run any time an object is accessed, so it really comes down to what the archive rules are for that object. That having been said, its unlikely that a workflow rule will exist to "unarchive" an object when the due date is changed. You'll likely need to do that manually.

Comment: I believe @user2582 is referencing the standard Salesforce archiving of activities https://na8.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/activities_archived.htm and nothing done with custom Workflow Rules.

Comment: @user2582, Ahh, that would be a horse of a different color! Again, the advice to open the Developer Console to see what happens would be the most reliable. Off hand, I'd expect it to require manual intervention to change the flag since no rules would likely fire to operate on the object/record.

Comment: I think the issue with trying to reproduce in a DevOrg is I'm guessing Salesforce handles the archiving asynchronously, so setting something exactly 365 days in the past isn't going to automatically archive. To test any unarchiving hypothesis would require potentially observing a record multiple days after confirming it has been archived, and seeing if it was been unarchived. Or, if someone has first hand knowledge or experience of this, they could answer definitively.

Comment: @Mikey, I wasn't suggesting trying to reproduce what you're referring to in a DevOrg but instead to open the **Developer Console** to look at the log to see what happens when one changes the date of an archived activity.

Comment: I added that bit due to assuming one wouldn't want to be monkeying around with data in a production environment. ;)